# Need to add value into my URL while doing HTTP post request using Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a OTP type of registration for my react native based mobile app. By using google cloud function to generate otp and post http request to my SMS provider.

The problem i am facing is that, whenever i try to add the random code to my sms provider url with `${code}`, the message simply displays the same `${code}` not the randomly generated code.

In other words, don't know how to interpolate the code into my url (as i am a newbie).

Here is my code for Random Number :

```
const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000));
```

And my request using request package is as follows:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://smsprovider.com/numbers=${numbers}&route=2&message=Your OTP is ${code}',
    body: {
        numbers: phone,
        code: code
    },
    json: true
};
```

So, whenever I get a message, it says `Your OTP is ${code}`. But what I actually need is to show the random number generated by the math.floor function. Expected "Your OTP is 5748"

Kindly guide

Answer (score 1):

For string interpolation with JavaScript be sure to use the

```
`
```

character instead of

```
'
```

Try this instead:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: `http://smsprovider.com/numbers=${numbers}&route=2&message=Your OTP is ${code}`,
    body: {
        numbers: phone,
        code: code
    },
    json: true
};
```

Comment: Changed and checked, now getting Error: could not handle the request in postman !, But without changing to ` from ' , i got phone(from google cloud user get function) passed to url, but couldn't succeed with code

Comment: @Arvindh, make sure you're encoding the URI. You likely have spaces in the URI.

Comment: As am a newbie, any example for encodeURIComponent() with my example ?

Comment: @Arvindh [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Spaces ? you mean the part after message ? Actually its working even with spaces , as i am getting text message but whats the prob is i am not getting the code in the text instead i am getting ${code}

Answer (score 0):

[String interpolation](https://campushippo.com/lessons/how-to-do-string-interpolation-with-javascript-7854ef9d) and [url encoding](https://love2dev.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-encodeuri-and-encodeuricomponent/) are two distinct paradigms, one doesn't replace the other.

- string interpolation allows you to dynamically insert a variable's content into a string with `${}`. For this to work you must enclose your string between back quotes as @Ben Beck instructed. Some interpreters will be forgiving, meaning that even if you use single quotes, the interpreter will nonetheless parse the string with the interpolation, however not all interpreters do that, and it is bad practice to rely on it. Make sure you format these correctly.
- url component encoding converts the url parameters containing special characters into a valid uri component with `encodeURIComponent()`. This is how you get rid of spaces and other special characters, however it might not be needed here as most browsers do that for you. Use Chrome to be sure, but again  it is good practice to write fully portable code, I recommend to encode any parameter featuring any special character.

The fact that your Postman test failed is most certainly due to a faulty request. [Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhAqc.png) for a working Postman POST request based on your case, leveraging [Pre-request Script](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts/).

While testing with your code directly (not through Postman), if you keep getting the literal `${code}` in place of the actual value, it likely means that the definition `const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000))` is not in the same scope as the interpolation call. Check below for an example of working script using both string interpolation and url encoding based on your case:

```
const request = require('request');

const code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8999 + 1000));

var p1 = encodeURIComponent(`Your OTP is ${code}`);
var uri = `http://smsprovider.com/?message=${p1}`;

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: uri,
  json: true
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
  else {
      console.log(error);
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

same but without url encoding and with the `message` parameter embedded in body element:

```
var uri = `http://smsprovider.com/`;

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: uri,
  body: {
    message: `Your OTP is ${code}`,
  },
  json: true
};
```